# Calculated Fields and language packs

Tags: calculated-column, language-pack, calculated-column-formula

We are programmatically deploying a calculated field in a Sharepoint 2010 website using a site collection feature. Now we need to add localization support for a number of diff languages, so we had to install language packs.
We are having a problem with that calculated field because the formula syntax changes on each language, so when activating that site collection feature on a non-English site collection, that field’s deploy throws and error saying that the formula syntax has a problem.

Is there a way to deploy the same calculated field in different site collections using different languages?

Thanks